# Child classes not saved in database in ASP.Net MVC Identity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.Net Identity model and have tried to create child classes of my ApplicationUser class. I want to save them in a different table in my database:

```
[Table("Persons")]
public class Person : ApplicationUser{...}
```

I create the person classes this way in my seed method:

```
 Person testUser = new Person();
 UserManager.Create(testUser);
```

But this only creates entries in the ApplicationUser table in my database. After creating them I try to get the Person-Data using the user ID:

```
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId()

using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var result = context.PersonModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userID);
}
```

But the table is always empty. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: What does UserManager.Create do, show the code.

Comment: @Jaanus `UserManager` is provided by the MVC framework the OP has (almost certainly) not written this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `UserManager.Create()` is expecting an `ApplicationUser` object rather than a `Person` and, as such, just treats it as a `ApplicationUser`.

You should just add your application-specific properties to the `ApplicationUser` class rather than inheriting from it. A tutorial describing the process is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

In a nutshell you simply need to add properties inside this class definition in the /Models/identity.cs file:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
```

then do the necesary migration brouhaha.

in fact, my version of MVC helpfully contains a comment with a link to that very tutorial in Identity.cs YMMV :-)